# Chrome --enable-precise-memory-info doesn't work and performance.memory is still bucketized

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I have to test memory usage of some pages in Chrome on Windows programmatically.

Here is my Chrome version (60.0.3112.113 - Official Build - 64-bit)
[image]

Following [Chromium Command Line Switches Documentation](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) I ran Chrome with `--enable-precise-memory-info` flag:

[image]

Then in the opened Chrome instance I tried to check value of `window.performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize`

but looks like inspite of `--enable-precise-memory-info` flag this info is still bucketized.

[image]

even in Chrome Task Manager (Shift + Esc) I see that memory usage is grows up by about 1 Mb after each execution of:

```
for(let i=0;i<100000;i++) {a.push('sdftgkljhghertyukytedtreut56ytirty7uikty' +i)}
```

I found only one outdated discussion concerning this [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=393251) even if the issue exists I would expect to find more discussions online.

If I do something wrong - what is my mistake?

If this flag is not supported anymore then what is the new correct way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Er, actually it sounds like a bug worth reporting on https://crbug.com

Comment: @wOxxOm Good idea. I've opened a new issue there: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=765998

Comment: @Alexander Was an instance of Chrome open when you launched second instance of Chrome with flag set?

Comment: @guest271314 Thank you. Yes, I closed all the instances and even checked in Task Manager that there is no any Chrome process running. But I still see the same behavior.

Comment: @Alexander Cannot reproduce at Chromium 60. Have you tried launching with `--user-data-dir` set to a different directory than default Chrome configuration folder?

Comment: Good idea. I tried and this flag worked, so generally my Chrome doesn't ignore flags. I ran chrome with **chrome --user-data-dir=C:\chrome-dev-profile-test** and in **chrome://version/** I see **Profile Path: C:\chrome-dev-profile-test\Default**

Comment: I've installed another version of Chrome (Dev this time) and there it works. Please find the version and screen-shots in an issue I previosly opened: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=765998

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find the reason why `--enable-precise-memory-info` doesn't work, so any help with that will be appritiated.

Meanwhile I found another way to do it even and I decided to share it.

I created a chrome extension and added a listener for `chrome.processes.onUpdatedWithMemory` in its background.js.

It gives me updated information concerning chrome processes including memory usage (the `privateMemory` field), **but this solution has two problems**:

1. To use chrome.processes I have to run the extension on [Dev channel only](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index#dev_apis).
2. Collecting memory usage information this way incurs [extra CPU usage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/processes#event-onUpdatedWithMemory).

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome 68+ you can now sample once every 50ms for scripts served from the same origin as the webpage (eTLD+1). This means you probably don't need `--enable-precise-memory-info` anymore.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/7c7847f69de403f6c798dfccba10812039a60480

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to close all opened chrome window (cmd + q) before run /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --enable-precise-memory-info